# Getting HTML attr. with ViewContainerRef?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding a component to my template via `*ngFor`

```
<div class="filter-group" *ngFor="let type of entityTypes">
  <filter-filter-group [type]="type" id="{{type.uri}}"></filter-filter-group>
</div>
```

And in my component I am getting my ViewChrildren like so

```
  @ViewChildren(FilterGroupComponent, { read: ViewContainerRef }) filterGroup: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

`this.filterGroup` now contains my components which is exactly what I want as I then use the component Factory to dynamically insert components to each viewChild.

As you can see in the `tmpl`. each component has an `id="{{type.uri}}"`
Is there a way to get the value of id?

I have searched far and wide and so far am a little lost on how to achieve this. NativeElement could be an option, but I believe that is only available with ElementRef?

Possible Solution:

```
console.log(group['_data'].renderElement.id);
```

this gives me the id.... but i don't think this would be the way to do it? I mean it works, but feels wrong.

Comment: doing `console.dir(group)` inside the forEach, what does this show?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli actually console.log(group['_data'].renderElement.id); outputs the ID, but this seems really weird to get it like that... thoughts?

Comment: is `group` a nativeElement element? I mean, if you `console.log(group)` do you get an html printed in your console?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli no it's a ViewContainerRef containing a '_data' child which contains a list of properties including ID. So technically i can get the ID this was, but it feels wrong...

Comment: if Im not mistaken, then, the ViewContainerRef has an elementRef as a child, which in turn has a nativeElement child (the HTML element per se). So you should be able to do `group.elementRef.nativeElement.id` to get the id

Comment: Another aproach is adding index to the ngFor such as `<div class="filter-group" *ngFor="let type of entityTypes; let index = index">` and then using that index to access your `entityTypes[index].type.uri`

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli thats it! How did I not see that in the console?! If you put this up as an answer, I'll mark it as correct1

Comment: adding it, sorry it took me a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewContainerRef` has an `elementRef` as a child, which in turn has a `nativeElement` child (the HTML element per se). So you should be able to do `group.elementRef.nativeElement.id` to get the id

Note: Be aware that using `console.log(element)` that returns an HTML element will print the element as HTML, for these cases instead use `console.dir`

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="filter-group" *ngFor="let type of entityTypes">
  <filter-filter-group [type]="type" #mycomp id="{{type.uri}}"></filter-filter-group>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChildren('mycomp') mycompRef: any;

someEvent() {
   console.log(this.mycompRef); // in this object you will get the id
}
```

Comment: This seems to work in theory, but it isn't typed as ViewContainerRef once I remove the { read: ViewContainerRef }. I will need to play with this a bit

Answer (score 0):

```js
@ViewChildren("vc", {read: ViewContainerRef}) containers: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>
    
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.containers.map(container => console.log(container["_lContainer"][0].id))
  this.createLayout();
}
```

This worked for me in Angular 10